# Xcode 9.4.1 Could not build module and redefinition of module - Can't Build

Tags: build, cocoapods, xcode9.4

[image: image of errors in Xcode]

Encountering this issue in Xcode, solutions I've tried:

- Enabled modules to **YES** and **NO**
- Reinstalled Xcode 9.4.1 by deleting 9.4.1 and `~/Library/Developer`
- Downgraded command lines tools to 9.4.1
- Downgraded Cocoapods to 1.4.0 from 1.5.3

I'm at a loss at this point can someone point me to the right direction here? I've already spent an entire day on this. Other projects build fine though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I SOLVED IT!

XCode was adding the following `Header Search Paths`:

```
/usr/include/libxml2 recursive
/usr/include/libxml2 non-recursive
```

But `libxml2` is already included in the `SDK` from `XCode.app` via `$(inherited)` search path so everything was conflicting.

Removed those two `/usr/include/libxml2` paths at the top of my folder hierarchy fixed it!

Thank the XCode gods.

Comment: could you add more details? how did you remove them?

Comment: I have been looking in the various paths that Xcode has for the 'Hello' sample of Vapor, but there are no such entries. Where exactly did you re-arrange things or removed 'duplicates'?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the resolution? Was this a project-specific issue? Did you update build settings? If so, where in Build Settings.

Comment: 1-) Open Terminal
2-) Paste this line to terminal /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include
3-) delete the extra libxml files (In my case there was extra "libxml 1" and "modulemap" files)
4-) Restart xcode and run

Answer (score 2):

**Error: redefinition of module**

I got `redefinition of module` when was working on own framework and added a first `.m` file (as a part of Cocoa Touch Class) and created `module.modulemap` file. Please note that this error is shown even if you do not add a path into `Module Map File`

To solve this issue I just renamed a `module.modulemap` to `ModuleName.modulemap`

Answer (score -4):

Try removing Command-line tools and build your project

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

To Reinstall:

```
xcode-select --install
```