# How do I use libproc.h in a modular Swift framework?

Tags: macos, module, frameworks, module-map

I've followed all the steps from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27776497/3939277) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51255621/3939277) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24103169/3939277), and I'm still stuck.

I need to use [the function `proc_pidpath` in `libproc.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498/darwin/libproc.c) to get the path of a BSD process by its PID. However, `libproc.h` is not a modular header, so I can't include it in my umbrella header:

[image: a line of code reading "#import <libproc.h>" with the error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"]

Fair enough; now I try to include it in my module map:

```
framework module My_Modular_Framework {
    umbrella header "My_Modular_Framework.h"

    private header "/usr/include/libproc.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

Well now I get this error-vomit where it seems like it thinks many system modules/headers are within my project:

[image: A long list of errors like "Redeclaration of module SomeSystemModule"]

I can't figure out what else to do. Like I said, I already tried following all the steps of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27776497/3939277) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51255621/3939277) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24103169/3939277) without any success. **What can be done here? How can I use `proc_pidpath`? Is there another, more Swift-in-modular-framework friendly way to get a path from a process ID?**

I don't want to enable "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" because that defeats the purpose of a modular framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`libproc.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498/darwin/libproc.h) *and* [`libproc.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498/darwin/libproc.c) are open-source ([APSL 2.0](http://www.opensource.apple.com/apsl)) as a part of Apple's [Darwin](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Darwin/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001006) project, you can just include them (under the terms of the license, of course) in your project. Since neither imports any non-modular headers, you can compile it yourself and the compiler won't complain!

Comment: Thank you for this point! I am trying to `cp libproc.h /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include` on my MacBook Pro.  Unfortunately, the system said `cp: ./libproc.h: Operation not permitted`. It seems that Apple does not allow us to change an official SDK.

Comment: This project shows how you can make your own swift LibProc from the macos-provided libproc.h:  https://github.com/themittenmac/TrueTree/tree/master/Src/ProcLib

Comment: @cxwangyi you're trying to copy a file into the `Xcode.app` bundle, but that bundle is read-only. To apply my answer to your project, you'd want to copy it into your project instead