# Is there any alternative for /proc in macOS?

Tags: c++, macos

There are no `/proc` in macOS, however I want to get infomation about my system such as:

1. /proc/loadavg
2. /proc/cpuinfo
3. /proc/meminfo
4. /proc/mounts
5. /proc/stat

Is there any alternatives in macOS for that?

Comment: Analogous info is mostly available via commands in macOS, rather than being mapped into the filesystem. See [serverfault: "How can I get CPU count and total RAM from the OS X command line?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/112711/how-can-i-get-cpu-count-and-total-ram-from-the-os-x-command-line) for some examples.

Comment: "/proc" is Linux.  MacOS is emphatically *NOT* Linux: it's a BSD derivative.  You can look [here](https://macdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/programmatically-retrieving-system-information-on-mac/) for `system_profiler`, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073677/how-do-i-use-libproc-h-in-a-modular-swift-framework) for `libproc`.  There might be other options, depending on your OS version.

Comment: @paulsm4 no, "/proc" is emphatically NOT Linux, [it is UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) and pre-dates Linux by 8 years. It has been available in BSD for decades, before being (currently) phased out, which is a different matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In MacOS, you can get all this informations in CLI with **sysctl** command.

```
sysctl -a //for all information
or
sysctl hw.memsize //for memory
sysctl hw.ncpu //cpu info
```